# How to add scraped data to models?

Tags: python, django, beautifulsoup

I am trying to put my scraped news links with BeautifulSoup4 to my Django models. I don't know proper way to do it, so here is my experiment:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from artisporto.models import Naujienos
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

def Save():
    url ="http://www.basketnews.lt/lygos/59-nacionaline-krepsinio-asociacija/2013/naujienos.html"
    r = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content)
    nba = soup.select('div.title > a')
    for title in nba:
            save_it = Naujienos(title = title.text) # Here I get syntax error
            save_it.save()
```

I commented the place where I get my syntax error. So, what is the proper way to do it? If  my way is right, where is my mistake?

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: please post exception and traceback

Comment: invalid syntax (views.py, line 13)

Comment: @IrmantasŽelionis is the spacing in your post the same spacing in your `.py` file?

Comment: @IrmantasŽelionis we need a full error traceback.

Comment: Yes, it is. Is there a problem with it?

Comment: Here is full traceback: http://dpaste.com/1WG53JW/

Comment: So is it a good way to do it? If not, can you link me to it or show the example?

Comment: As mentioned above, his looks like an indentation error. Convert all your hard tabs to spaces, and use 4 spaces everywhere.